# Swift optimize if else condition

Tags: swift

I have a function with a long if else condition to check whether all the details are valid or not. However, I would like to optimize the if-else condition.

```
if emailInput!.isEmailValid && passwordInput!.isPasswordValid && usernameInput!.isUserNameValid && testConfirmedPwd == true && photoPick !=  "image1" {
    print("valid")
} else {
    print("not valid")
}
```

Because I would like to know which part of the condition is not valid and `print` it out instead of doing it all together. For example, If `emailInput` is invalid when others are valid.

Comment: If cond1 {if cond2 {print("ok") }else{print("cond2 Ko")} else {print("cond1 ko")}

Comment: It depends on that what does it mean for you "to know which part of the condition is not valid". You can split this in six functions that checks values and returns booleans,, for example: if emailInputOk() && passwordOk() && userNameInputOk...etc and to print or do something else within this functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know which part of the condition fails, you can check each case individually and react accordingly:

```
if !emailInput!.isEmailValid {
    // Invalid email
} else if !passwordInput!.isPasswordValid {
    // Invalid pwd
} else if !usernameInput!.isUserNameValid {
    // Invalid username
} else if !testConfirmedPwd {
    // Invalid pwd
} else if photoPick == "image1" {
    // Invalid image
}else{
    print("valid")
}
```

Comment: It is nice and clean also it is easy to read and understanding

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is store each value in a boolean array, and loop through that array, and then print the results of the if statement:

```
let conditions = [(emailInput!.isEmailValid), (passwordInput!.isPasswordValid)...]

var index = 0

for condition in conditions{
    if(condition){
        print("Condition \(index) is true")
      }
    else{
        print("Condition \(index) is false")
    }
   index += 1
}
```

You could also link it to a separate array that stores the names and use the index to take a name out of that array so you know the condition name, not just the number.

Doing it this way also makes it very easy to add a condition later on.

Answer (score 1):

One explicit way to do it is to have a `guard` statement for every confition. Like so:

```
guard emailInput.isEmailValid else { print("Email is invalid") } 
guard passwordInput.isPasswordValid else { print("Password is invalid") } 
.
.
.
print("Valid")
```

Another cool way to do the same will be to use tuples. Like:

```
typealias Condition = (isValid: Bool, name: String)

let conditions: [Condition] = [
    (emailInput.isEmailValid, "Email"),
    (passwordInput.isPasswordValid, "Password"),
    .
    .
]

let isInputValid = conditions.reduce(true) { (aggregate, condition) -> Bool in
    if !condition.isValid { print("Invalid \(condition.name)") }
    return aggregate && condition.isValid
}

guard isInputValid else { return }
// handle valid input now
```

This allows checking all the conditions and not just exiting at the first invalid condition. Output looks like this:

```
    Invalid Password
    Invalid Date of birth
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to check all conditions separately:

```
if emailInput!.isEmailValid == true{
   if passwordInput!.isPasswordValid == true {
      if usernameInput!.isUserNameValid == true {
           if testConfirmedPwd == true {
                 if photoPick !=  "image1" {
                    print("valid")
                  } else { print("photoPick is not valid") }
           }  else { print("testConfirmedPwd is not valid") }
       } else { print("isUserNameValid is not valid") }
   }  else { print("isPasswordValid is not valid") }
}  else { print("Email is not valid") }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
guard emailInput!.isEmailValid else 
{
 print("email invalid")
}

guard passwordInput!.isPasswordValid else 
{
 print("password is invalid")
}

guard usernameInput!.isUserNameValid else 
{
 print("username invalid")
}

guard testConfirmedPwd else 
{
 print("testConfirmedpwd error")
}

guard photoPick !=  "image1" else 
{
 print("photo pick is not image1")
}
```

This makes the code more readable and does not check other conditions if one condition fails

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you have to check each condition separately and keep updating string or flag for each to understand is it valid or not.

```
let strErrorMessage : String = “.”

if emailInput!.isEmailValid
{
    strErrorMessage = “Invalid email ” + strErrorMessage
}
else
{
    strErrorMessage = “Valid email ” + strErrorMessage
}

if passwordInput!.isPasswordValid
{
    strErrorMessage = “Invalid password ” + strErrorMessage
}
else
{
    strErrorMessage = “Valid password ” + strErrorMessage
}


if usernameInput!.isUserNameValid
{
    strErrorMessage = “Invalid username ” + strErrorMessage
}
else
{
     strErrorMessage = “Valid username ” + strErrorMessage
}

if testConfirmedPwd == true
{
    strErrorMessage = “Invalid testConfirmedPwd ” + strErrorMessage
}
else
{
    strErrorMessage = “Invalid testConfirmedPwd ” + strErrorMessage
}

if photoPick !=  "image1
{
    strErrorMessage = “Invalid image ” + strErrorMessage
}
else
{
    strErrorMessage = “Valid image ” + strErrorMessage
}

print(strErrorMessage)
```